# usepackage{doxygen} in refman.tex doesn't allow me create a pdf file

Tags: pdf, doxygen

I'm working on creating a manual, using Doxygen 1.8.6, MikTex, pdflatex on a Win7 system.

Unfortunately it is not possible to create a pdf file with the "original" refman.tex.

Starting the make file is ok, no error messages but it will never finalise. CPU usage is 25% and will not stop working but nothing happens. Need to stop it manually, but no pdf file is created.

But if I adjust the refman.tex = delete the entry "/usepackage{doxygen}" then it works without any problem and I get the pdf I want to see ;)

(btw: problem does not exist with 1.8.2 but with 1.8.5 
But I can't use 1.8.2 for this project because 1.8.2 will not produce any refman.tex at all ;) )

If I missed some information or a more detailed description is necessary please let me know.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.